# Segmentation Fault Core Dumped with a Vector Nested in a Vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a class for a Matrix using standard library vectors. I am using a vector within a vector to setup the Matrix, one vector represents columns, the other (vector) represents the rows and the values stored in the rows. Here are the variables and the constructor.

Variables:

```
 int columns;
 int rows;
 std::vector<std::vector<int> > v;
```

Constructor:

```
 Matrix(int a, int b){
std::cout << "Input Recieved.. Construct Began" << std::endl;
rows = a;
columns = b;
// Subtract one to put them in a proper array format
rows = rows - 1;
columns = columns - 1;
//Creates the columns
v.reserve(columns);
//Creates the Rows .. Code is ran for every column, this is where the values are set
for(int i = 0; i <= columns; i++){

  v[i].reserve(rows);
  std::cout << "Column " << i  + 1 << " Created, with " << rows + 1<< " Rows" << std::endl;


  //Sets the values of the rows .. is ran for every column
  for(int e = 0; e <= rows; e++){
    if(i == 19){
      std::cout << "Column 20 row setting has begun" << std::endl;
    }


    v[i][e] = 2;

    if(i == 19){
    std::cout << "Made it past the line" << std::endl;
  }

    std::cout << "Row " << e + 1 << " Set in Column " << i + 1<< ", with Value " << v[i][e] << std::endl;

    if(i == 19){
      std::cout << "Column 20 row setting has finished" << std::endl;
    }
  }



}

}
```

Right now it seems to be able to create everything except the last vector , then I get the Segmentation Fault.. For a more complete source code there is this http://pastebin.com/AB59bPMR .

Comment: Well, did you step through your code in a debugger and see where the error is?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Segmentation fault (core dumped) is all I get.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried most of that already (except the rubber ducky), and for some reason I haven't been able to solve this problem, which I why I came to stack exchange, I asked other friends, and read up on related questions on here too still didn't seem to help. When I was debugging I narrowed it down to v[i][e] = 2; doesn't seem to want to create the rows in the last column, but I didn't know what to do from there. Which is why I am here.

Comment: You have a couple of off by one errors.  `i <= columns` should be `i < columns` and `e < rows` should be `e < rows`.

Comment: @NathanOliver just tested that (and it works!), but then won't that just entirely skip the last vector? For example if I had 4 columns, the 4th wouldn't be created because i(4) would not be less than columns (4)

Comment: @Noah Indexes are 0 based so if a vector has 4 elements then the valid index are in the range `[1, 3]`

Comment: @NathanOliver AH so that's what it was, I misunderstood that on the vector documentation I suppose. That's what I get for programming at 3 am. That's the solution then, I just had to change `columns = columns - 1;` to `columns = columns;` same for rows, and fix the loop like you said and it seems to work well now. Thanks for your help Nathan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the method `resize()` to make a matrix how big you want

```
matrix.resize(rows, vector < int >(columns));
```

Comment: The reserve function I used should do the same thing? ` v.reserve(columns); and   v[i].reserve(rows);  `

Comment: No, reserve and resize are different. You're using the wrong one.

Comment: @kfsone tested using resize, same result (doesn't work same problem as before). I was originally using resize, but changed it to reserve once I started having problems with program. You are right though, I read up on resize and I should be using it, changed it in my code. I still have the Segmentation Fault problem

Comment: you need to say where the Segmentation Fault is happening. 
put  "cout" in your code and see where it brakes

Comment: @MilosRadosavljevic I used cout in my code already and it seems to be happening on the last vector(column) and it breaks at `v[i][e] = 2;`

Answer (score 1):

Made a simple mistake with the for loops `i <= columns` should've been `i < columns` same with the rows. Also I shouldn't have subtracted 1 from the column and rows variables.

`rows = rows - 1;
columns = columns - 1;`

Should've been

`rows = rows;
columns = columns;`

Answer (score 1):

```
columns = columns - 1;
//Creates the columns
v.reserve(columns);
//Creates the Rows .. Code is ran for every column, this is where the values are set
for(int i = 0; i <= columns; i++){
```

Lets take the simple case of a 1x1 Matrix:

```
columns = columns - 1 => columns = 0
v.reserve(0);    // should be resize
for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++)
```

You would then try to access past the end of the array: the 1st element (element[0]) of an empty (size==0) array. The same is true for any other value - you access past the end of the array.

Leave columns as it is.

```
Matrix(int a, int b){
    std::cout << "Input Recieved.. Construct Began" << std::endl;
    rows = a;
    columns = b;

    //Creates the columns
    v.resize(columns);

    //Creates the Rows .. Code is ran for every column, this is where the values are set
    for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
```